# Program outputs wrong string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a program were the user inputs a drivers first name, last name, their team leader's id, phone number and area code. Then it stores the info into the database, but instead of storing the leader's id, it finds the teams id that is corresponding to the leader's id and stores it.

**Example**

Drivers Table

```
driver_id | first_name | last_name | phone | area_code | team_id
```

Teams Table

```
team_id | leader_id | student_id
```

So the program finds the `team_id` that corresponds to the `leader_id` that the user enters.

**Problem**

My problem is that if the `leader_id` doesn't exist, that means that the team doesn't exist, so the program should output this line of code `header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Team Doesn't Exist");` ( because the table is empty ) but the program outputs this line of code `header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Success!");`, which should be outputted if the leader_id exists.

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

require '../../connect.php';

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$leader_id = $_POST['leader_id'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$area_code = $_POST['area_code'];

if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($phone) && !empty($leader_id)) {

    if(is_numeric($leader_id) && is_numeric($phone) && is_numeric($area_code)) {

        $get_team_id = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT team_id FROM teams WHERE leader_id = $leader_id");

        if($get_team_id) {

            $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO drivers (first_name, last_name, phone, area_code, team_id) SELECT '$first_name', '$last_name', '$phone', '$area_code', team_id FROM teams WHERE leader_id = '$leader_id'");

            if($result) {

                header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Success!");

            } else {

                header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Sorry we ran into an error");

            }

            header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Team Exists");

        } else {

            header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Team Doesn't Exist");

        }


    } else {

        header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Please add a number for the Leader ID, Phone Number and Area Code");

    }
} else if (empty($first_name) || empty($last_name) || empty($leader_id) || empty($phone)) {

    header("Location: ../../../admin.php?message=Please add you're input values");

}
```

?>

Comment: 0 or  '' is not empty.. you might want to check your values from the post action

Comment: You should also add exit after header; because header doesn't end the execution and without exit everything bellow header is executed before redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code for your Condition
`if(mysqli_num_rows($get_team_id)>0)`

instead of
`if($get_team_id)`